# Singularity of small cardinals under AD

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, cardinals

It appears to be quite a folklore result that under AD we know which small well-orderable cardinals (for my purposes I mean below $\omega_\omega$) are regular, namely only $\omega,\omega_1,\omega_2$. My question regards proofs of these results:

> Where could I find the proof that under AD only the mentioned cardinals are regular?

I can recall that $\omega_1$ is regular thanks to countable choice for reals, and I guess regularity of $\omega_2$ might follow from measurability, but I'm mostly interested in a proof of singularity of all larger cardinals up to $\omega_\omega$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (By the way, I would not call these results "folklore". It is well documented who proved them, where, and how.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I couldn't have found a reference as for who proved these, so I thought it's a folklore result (which, I now see, it's not). Feel free to repost your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proof can be found in Kanamori's book **The higher infinite**. The result follows from work of Solovay on the theory of uniform indiscernibles and work of Martin on projective scales. Look at sections 14, 28, and 30 of the book.

A different approach (using the infinite partition properties of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, themselves due to Solovay and Martin) , is due to Kleinberg, and the details can be found on his book **Infinitary combinatorics and the axiom of determinateness**. For modern extensions of Kleinberg's results, see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2323).

A related open problem (probably due to Steve Jackson): Under determinacy, is it true that the cofinality function is *non-decreasing* when restricted to *double successor* cardinals below $\Theta$?

(The answer is obviously negative if we do not restrict our attention to *successor* cardinals. It is negative as well if we do not further restrict to double successors. For instance, $\aleph_{\omega 2 +1}$ is regular, while $\aleph_{\omega 2 +2}$ has cofinality $\aleph_{\omega+1}$. A proof of the conjecture below $\mathbf\delta^1_5=\aleph_{\omega^{\omega^\omega}+1}$ can be found in Jackson-Khafizov, *Descriptions and cardinals below $\mathbf\delta^1_5$*. Jackson's theory of descriptions can be used to verify the conjecture below $\aleph_{\epsilon_0}$, but a different approach would be needed for the general problem. Thanks to Yizheng Zhu for noticing the mistake in my first formulation of the question.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed reference.

Comment: So the open problem is to get singular successor cardinals of cofinality $<\omega_2$ below $\Theta$?

Comment: $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ is regular, @Asaf. There are many regular successor and many singular successor cardinals below $\Theta $.

Comment: These structure consequences of $\sf AD$ always feel funky to me. One day I'll get the hang of it...

Comment: After your edit, I'm not so sure about my previous comment anymore! :-)